# Using external symbol in arm assembly

Tags: arm, inline-assembly

I am facing a trivial prblem.

I am doing an ldr r0, _buff
in arm assembly, where _buff is defined in a c file. _buff is not static.

How should I define external linkage in assembly file (similar to extern in C)
is it required or is there anything which I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to. If the symbol can't be found in the source file, it'll be assumed to be defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to do that. If *_buff* has been defined as global in the C file, you can compile and build the files together:

```
arm-none-gnuaebi-gcc -o output assembly.s cfile.c
```

You can also **compile** them separately, it's also going to work. But _buff does not exist, you will get a link error.